# Can I retrieve queries based on two properties?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from Firebase. The retrieving data should be visible and have appropriate property "vis" and flag "true". It's a quite simple task. But I also want specific order, so in the beginning should go child with property "pos" equal 1, than 2, and etc.

There is my current line of code

```
mQuery = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("vis").equalTo("true");
```

The data structure looks like:

```
common
 code:"common"
 name:"Common"
 pos:"5"
 vis:"false"

 court
 code: "court"
 name: "Court reform"
 pos: "2"
 vis: "false"

 june12
 code: "june12"
 name: "12 June"
 pos: "1"
 vis: "true"
```

Comment: You can combine the two values that you want to use into a single property, i.e. `vis_pos: "true_1"`. Then you can order/filter on that property and get the results you want. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Thank you Frank!

I have already seen that question before. I had different task. 

I want to retrieve data that have value "true" for properties "vis" and at the same type this retrieving data should be displayed in ascending order.  That's why I use another property "pos". 

I found simple solution: I deleted property "vis" and changed the line of code in my app.
mQuery = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("pos").startAt("100");
So after that, I retrieve only data that start at "100".

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  From the docs:

> You can only use **one** order-by method at a time. Calling an order-by method multiple times in the same query throws an error.
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

You can limit the Range of data using a filter function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/retrieve-data#filtering_data

Be sure to watch the [Firebase for SQL devs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) series. Specifically, the video on [denormalization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA&index=6&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) (#6) and the follow up Multi-path updates (#7).  Multipath updates can be performed server side using [Cloud function triggers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0).